# Does the set of limit points always have measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $P$ be a Borel set, does the following set have measure zero(w.r.t to an arbitrary Borel measure)?
$$
\{x \notin P : d(x, P) = 0\}
$$
where $d(x, P) = \inf_{z \in P} \{ d(x, z) \}$ and $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the distance function.

Comment: No. A simple counterexample is $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$. The set of limit points is $[0,1]$ which has not measure zero.

Comment: What about if we add the restriction: measure of $P$ is strictly positive?

Comment: $\left(\mathbb{Q}\cup[0,0.5]\right)\cap[0,1]$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is an **open** set $P\subset[0,1]$ such that $\{x\notin P:d(x,P)=0\}$ has positive measure.